# Tableau calculated field

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I have data table with the total of health insurance coverage per state for the period of 5 years, so I created a calculated field that calculates the yearly coverage per state by using the divide statement to calculate for that in this way **div(health insurance coverage,5)** and I titled it **Yearly coverage per state** and this worked as a measure.

The next step I want to execute for my analysis is to create another calculated field using the Yearly coverage measure to divide the Health insurance coverage to give the coverage rate per state for 5 years. I tried this **sum(Yearly coverage per state)/sum(Health insurance coverage)**, the calculation is valid but when I drag the **new field** to row section and drag the **states field** to the column section of my viz, it gives me one figure which is 0.20 for all states and that isnt what I am looking for. I tried it without the sum statement and its the same, tried both fields inside the divide statement and its giving me 0 for all states. I need it to calculate the individual health insurance coverage rate using that formula above. Please help!

Comment: did you try editing the format of the "new field"?

Comment: Yes, I did from automatic to sum. Still it didnt make any difference

Comment: is it possible to have a closer look at your issue? maybe a tableau public link ? can you share ?

Comment: https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/ijeoma.ike/viz/Workinprogress_16750037758870/Healthinsurancecoveragechange

Comment: your formula seems to be a circular reference. i mean if you perform [Yearly insurance coverage per state]/[Health Insurance Coverage Change 2010-2015] then you are just repeating the same calculation : [Health Insurance Coverage Change 2010-2015]/5, because divide by 5 will result in 20% for all the records. Is there any other formula that you are using , are the fields correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the situation:your formula seems to be a circular reference. i mean if you perform [Yearly insurance coverage per state]/[Health Insurance Coverage Change 2010-2015] then you are just repeating the same calculation : [Health Insurance Coverage Change 2010-2015]/5, because divide by 5 will result in 20% for all the records. Is there any other formula that you are using , are the fields correct ?
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I believe I  understand now, I repeated the same formula in excel and it gave me same 20%

Comment: then, mark this as "solved"